# How to fully remove Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I want to remove all existing SDK versions as well as Xcode 4.

Xcode 4 Guide says to do this:

```
sudo /Xcode4/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

But I don't have Xcode4 at this location and the only place I see it is under `/Developer/Applications`

I've already run the uninstall-devtools that was previously found in `/Developer/Applications` and then did a reinstall.

What else can I do to completely remove everything and start from scratch?

Comment: +1 for this question. I'm stuck with Xcode 4.1 and can't get 4.2 installed; uninstall-devtools script doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 194):

I use this command:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

---

**Edit** (1 year later):

If you've downloaded Xcode from the App Store, it's self-contained, as @mediaslave suggests. You can just drag it to the trash or use AppZapper (or a similar utility) to remove the developer tools.

If you're looking to update it, you can also do that straight through the App Store.

Comment: Xcode 4.3 does not have this.  It is a "normal" OS X app self contained. FYI

Comment: I tried to install 4.4 on top of 4.2 but the program crashed at startup. So I uninstalled 4.4, ran your command, reinstalled 4.4, and now things appear to work properly. Thank you

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo /[xcode-path]/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Normally, [xcode-path] means /Developer, but if you have multiple versions, for example 3 is the first installed, 4 is second, /Developer will be xcode 3's root derectory and /Xcode4 for xcode 4.

Answer (score 14):

Ensure Xcode, iOS Simulator, and the Mac App Store apps aren't running, then trying running the uninstall script at this (different!) location:

```
/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
```

This is where I found it.

Also delete `Install Xcode.app` from Applications folder, and Empty Trash.

Then run App Store again, and find/install Xcode.

Answer (score 7):

`su`    (or `sudo su`, whatever)

```
find / -name uninstall-devtools
```

This will reveal where the utility is...

Answer (score 7):

If you have XCode 4.3.1, just Move To Trash the **XCode.app** file in the **Applications** folder.

Comment: I would add "and then Empty the trash". It gives you 1 item if you didn't have anything in it before, but takes a while because it actually removes XCode from the Mac.

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed xcode from Mac App store, then you need to delete it from Launch pad. You can do this by locating xcode icon in launch pad, long click on the icon till it starts dancing. Then delete it and wait for a while till the xcode.app is deleted from /Application. If you manually delete xcode.app from /Application, App store will continue to think its installed and will not allow you to reinstall in future.

Comment: It may not be applicable anymore. I successfully uninstalled Xcode 4.6.1 by dragging it to trash directly without having any problems with Mac App Store thinking it's still installed on MacOsX 1.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to uninstall this by deleting it, but the AppStore still thought that it was installed.  I deleted some preferences files in my /private directory, which made the AppStore "forget" that I had installed Xcode.  I used the following command:

```
sudo find / -iname '*xcode*' 2> /dev/null | egrep '^/private.*' | xargs -I file sudo rm -rfv file
```

Which deleted the following files from my computer:

```
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeMAS_iOSSDK_6_1.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.XcodeMAS_iOSSDK_6_1.plist
/private/var/folders/7d/n34963zx62s7znxyzn3dn6bh0000gq/C/com.apple.Xcode.503/CachedSpecifications-Xcode
/private/var/folders/7d/n34963zx62s7znxyzn3dn6bh0000gq/C/com.apple.Xcode.503/CachedSpecifications-xcodebuild
/private/var/folders/7d/n34963zx62s7znxyzn3dn6bh0000gq/C/com.apple.Xcode.503
```

I do not know what these files are used for, but it made the AppStore forget that it was installed, which is what I needed to happen.  In my case, the AppStore was not allowing me to update to the new version of Xcode.

Comment: I removed all this. In fact I also removed pretty much every other *xcode* reference from my system but I still see this here: http://cl.ly/RYJ0. How to get rid of this?