# Installing xcode 4.1 for Lion after OSX Lion update?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

I just finished downloading the osx lion update on my snow leopard install.

Xcode 4.1 won't run now because it wants the Lion version to be running instead. However wen I go to the app store to install Xcode 4.1 lion it tells me it's already installed.

How can I uninstall Xcode 4.1 snow leopard so I can install lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app store doesn't detect that you have Xcode installed, it detects that you have the Xcode *installer* installed. That must still be around somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall XCode 4: [How to fully remove Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4)

After the uninstall, you go to the App Store and re-download/re-install XCode 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

You should uninstall Xcode first,

in a terminal window,

```
 sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```