# Mercurial produces strange messages

Tags: mercurial

I'm typing **hg st** as my regular ritual when working with Mercurial.
But today Mercurial is acting up on me, it produces

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 10, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
```

This same error appear when I type **hg branches** and any other **hg** commands.
 Do you know what is going on and how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
So I was running Mac OS X, and working with Xcode.
I have several Xcode versions in the machine,
some of them are Xcode4 (including Xcode beta versions).

I remember when I couldn't [uninstall Xcode4 from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4)
I delete the Xcode4 folder manually, and then the error appear every time I type **hg something**.

**EDIT:**
I uninstalled all Xcode versions, and Pythons still not working so I reInstall the OS, now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python installation is broken.

I don't know exactly what you've done for this to happen, but Python is unable to find the `os` module, this has nothing specific to do with Mercurial.

Depending on your operating system, the easiest way to resolve this will be to reinstall Python from scratch.

Comment: I will try to reinstall Python and report the result, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You reinstalled MacOSX completly ? There must be an easiest way to reinstall python on Mac :)

Comment: Yes, sadly. I'd appreciate when you show the link on how to reinstall python on Mac.

Comment: Sorry @Tuyen I'm not a Mac user at all... But maybe this page http://www.python.org/getit/mac/ can help the next time.