# Xcode Location on Disk

Tags: xcode4.3

I had installed Xcode from the AppStore and I am not sure where it got installed. I do not see a the usual path it gets installed - /Developer/Library. 
When I search for Xcode, it shows it is under Applications. All it shows is Xcode.app. I am unable to see any of the related Xcode files.

The problem I am facing because of this is, I am unable to uninstall Xcode from my system. Since I am not able to find the install location of Xcode, I am unable to run the uninstall-devtools command.

I have Xcode 4.3.3 and OS 10.7.4.

Would someone be able to help me with this?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all the Xcode stuff in the Finder, right-click the Xcode application and choose "Show Package Contents".  (An application is really a directory, but the Finder displays it as if it is a single file by default.)

In Terminal, you can do stuff like this:

```
ls -al /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. so where would I run the uninstall-devtools command?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no reason to run uninstall-devtools with the current versions of Xcode, and the uninstall-devtools script is no longer included as part of Xcode. Just drag the Xcode app to the Trash to uninstall it. (But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4.)

Comment: ok.. I think I should drag the Xcode app to trash because when I try to run uninstall-devtools, it is not able to find it..