# Xcode 5.0 hangs on linking - fails after a few minutes

Tags: xcode, linker, counter, xcode5, freeze

Just installed OS X 10.8.5 and upgraded from Xcode 4 to 5 and now I can't build any project anymore. I even tried a blank test project. When I build it for the simulator, it hangs for 10 minutes (if not more) on the "linking" stage, eats up all the free RAM that I have, then I get the error:

```
0  0x107520724  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x1075677c0  ld::tool::InputFiles::findDylib(char const*, char const*) + 830
2  0x107561fdc      mach_o::dylib::File<x86>::processIndirectLibraries(ld::dylib::File::DylibHandler*, bool) + 228
3  0x1075681f8  ld::tool::InputFiles::createIndirectDylibs() + 302
4  0x1075690e8  ld::tool::InputFiles::forEachInitialAtom(ld::File::AtomHandler&, ld::Internal&) + 514
5  0x107572186  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 48
6  0x107520b17  main + 669
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/Test 2-2013-09-14-175942.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (counter() < 0xffff), function nextCounter, file /SourceCache/ld64/ld64-224.1/src/ld/ld.hpp, line 102.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Other details that might help: I'm using a 3 years old mac mini 2.53ghz, 4GB ram. Also for some odd reasons the iphone simulator also hangs after a few seconds of being started manually.

At this stage I would really appreciate any idea, even remotely relevant, as I'm really stuck and can't work on any project anymore. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the only solution I found was to start with a clean slate. I originally started with xCode 3 on that machine and it looks like the multiple upgrades ever since then created some "pollution".

So I unistalled Xcode completely c.f. [How to fully remove Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4) before downloading it again from the store.