# Swift project crashes on launch - works with Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I create a new project in XCode 6 and select "Swift", it crashes whenever I try to open an Ad Hoc or In-House build.

I have no problem when I select "Objective-C" as the language, the app runs as per normal. I am using the exact same developer certificate and Provisioning Profile for both Swift and Objective-C.

Has anyone had any similar experiences? Could it perhaps be something to do with my dev environment?

I would also like to add that debugging the Swift app to the device from XCode works perfectly fine.

Another update - I have sent my project to another developer to build from their computer and it worked.

Many thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: How does it crash? Is there an error message, or a stack trace?

Comment: There's actually no error message at all - the app closes and returns to the home screen after flashing the default screen / image. I tried pulling the logs using the iPhone Configurator utility but I've been unable to get them to come through. My next steps will involve setting up Crashlytics to try and get some more information. I also have a bug report filed (18392655)

Comment: Weird, this definitely sounds like an Xcode bug. +1

Comment: How about a clean reinstall of Xcode?

Comment: Yeah I've been having this problem all throughout the Beta period for XCode 6. So I have installed a new version of XCode for each beta released. However, would you suggest that perhaps I try and clean out any more residual files as well? Perhaps by running:

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

Comment: I attempted to re-install Xcode again but I'm still having the same problem. I removede the xcode.app file and re-downloaded it - however, I couldn't find any "uninstall-devtools" going by this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that re-creating my certificate has solved the problem!

It's hard to say exactly, but it seems that any developer certificates created before Xcode 6 beta was released - don't build a Swift project properly. Let me know if anyone has had a similar experience!